# ARM linked template

Tags: azure, azure-resource-manager, azure-rm-template

**Requirments**:
I need to create two following resources in azure which is 'azure storage account' and 'azure storage sync service' using ARM Templates.

**Steps**:
I've two ARM template one is for creating 'azure storage account' another one is for creating 'azure storage sync service'.

1. Need to create a 'azure storage account' from template number one it has to return 'azure storage account resource-id'
2. Then need to create 'azure storage sync service' using that 'azure storage account resource-id'

i've tried with following arm templates but it does not work properly. anyone help me to get this ?

main template Storage sync service/deploy.json
{
"$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2019-04-01/deploymentTemplate.json#",
"contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
"parameters": {
"storageSyncServicesname": {
"type": "string",
"defaultValue": "",
"maxLength": 25
},
"Location": {
"type": "string",
"metadata": {
"defaultValue": ""
}
},
"SyncGroupName": {
"type": "string",
"defaultValue":"ServerA-P01",
"metadata": {
"description": "The name of the storage endpoint."
}
},
"serverID": {
"type": "string",
"defaultValue":"",
"metadata": {
"description": "The name of the storage endpoint."
}
},
"enableServerEndpoint": {
"type": "bool",
"defaultValue": false
},
"azureFileShareName": {
"type": "string",
"defaultValue": " ",
"metadata": {
"description": "The name of the file share."
}
},
"cloudendpoint": {
"type": "string",
"defaultValue": "bhendpoints",
"metadata": {
"description": "The name of the file share."
}
},
"storageAccountResourceId": {
"type": "securestring",
"defaultValue": "",
"metadata": {
"description": "The storage account access key."
}
},
"storageAccountTenantId": {
"type": "string",
"defaultValue": "",
"metadata": {
"description": "The storage server id."
}
},
"cloudTiering": {
"type": "string",
"metadata": {
"description": "descrip"
}
},
"volumeFreeSpacePercent": {
"type": "string",
"metadata": {
"description": "description"
}
},
"serverLocalPath": {
"type": "string",
"metadata": {
"description": "description"
}
},
"Datepolicy": {
"type": "string",
"metadata": {
"description": "description"
}
}
"variables": {
},
"resources": [

```
    {
        "type": "Microsoft.Resources/deployments",
        "apiVersion": "2021-04-01",
        "name": "linkedTemplate",
        "properties": {
        "mode": "Incremental",
        "templateLink": {
            "uri": "[uri(deployment().properties.templatelink.uri, 'C:\\Users\\User\\Desktop\\poc\\storageaccount\\deploy.json')]",
            "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0"
        },
        "parameters": {
            "deploymentFilePath": {
            "value": "[parameters('deploymentFilePath')]"
            }
        }
        }
    },
    {
        "type": "Microsoft.StorageSync/storageSyncServices",
        "apiVersion": "2022-06-01",
        "name": "[parameters('storageSyncServicesname')]",
        "location": "[parameters('Location')]",
        "properties": {
            "incomingTrafficPolicy": "AllowAllTraffic"
        }
    },
    {
        "type": "Microsoft.StorageSync/storageSyncServices/syncGroups",
        "apiVersion": "2022-06-01",
        "name": "[concat(parameters('storageSyncServicesname'), '/', if(not(empty(parameters('SyncGroupName'))), parameters('SyncGroupName'), 'defaultValue'))]",
        "dependsOn": [
             "[resourceId('Microsoft.StorageSync/storageSyncServices', parameters('storageSyncServicesname'))]

        ],
        "properties": {}
    },
    {
        "condition": "[parameters('enableServerEndpoint')]",
        "type": "Microsoft.StorageSync/storageSyncServices/syncGroups/cloudEndpoints",
        "apiVersion": "2022-06-01",
        "name": "[concat(parameters('storageSyncServicesname'), '/', parameters('SyncGroupName'), '/', parameters('cloudendpoint'))]",
        "dependsOn": [
            "[resourceId('Microsoft.StorageSync/storageSyncServices', parameters('storageSyncServicesname'))]",
            "[resourceId('Microsoft.StorageSync/storageSyncServices/syncGroups', parameters('storageSyncServicesname'), parameters('SyncGroupName'))]"
        ],
        "properties": {
            "storageAccountResourceId": "[reference('linkedTemplate').outputs.storageAccountResourceId.value]",
            "azureFileShareName": "[parameters('azureFileShareName')]",
            "storageAccountTenantId": "[parameters('storageAccountTenantId')]",
            "friendlyName": "[parameters('azureFileShareName')]"
        }
    },
    {
        "condition": "[parameters('enableServerEndpoint')]",
        "type": "Microsoft.StorageSync/storageSyncServices/syncGroups/serverEndpoints",
        "apiVersion": "2019-02-01",
        "name": "[concat(parameters('storageSyncServicesname'), '/', parameters('SyncGroupName'), '/', parameters('azureFileShareName'))]",
        "dependsOn": [
            "[resourceId('Microsoft.StorageSync/storageSyncServices', parameters('storageSyncServicesname'))]",
            "[resourceId('Microsoft.StorageSync/storageSyncServices/syncGroups/cloudEndpoints', parameters('storageSyncServicesname'), parameters('SyncGroupName'), parameters('cloudendpoint'))]"
        ],
        "properties": {
        "serverLocalPath": "[parameters('serverLocalPath')]",
        "cloudTiering": "[parameters('cloudTiering')]",
        "volumeFreeSpacePercent": "[parameters('volumeFreeSpacePercent')]",
        "tierFilesOlderThanDays": "[parameters('Datepolicy')]",
        "storageAccountResourceId":"[reference('linkedTemplate').outputs.storageAccountResourceId.value]"
        "serverResourceId": "[resourceId('Microsoft.StorageSync/storageSyncServices/registeredServers', parameters('storageSyncServicesname'), parameters('serverID'))]",
        "offlineDataTransfer": "Off",
        "initialDownloadPolicy": "NamespaceOnly",
        "localCacheMode": "UpdateLocallyCachedFiles",
        "initialUploadPolicy": "ServerAuthoritative"
    }
}
]
```

}

Lincked template storageaccount\deploy.json

{
"$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2019-04-01/deploymentTemplate.json#",
"contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
"parameters": {
"storageAccountName": {
"defaultValue": "msftstoragepoc1998",
"type": "String"
},

```
    "fileShareName": {
        "defaultValue": "fileshere1",
        "type": "String"
    },
    "location": {
        "type": "string",
        "defaultValue": "West US 2",
        "metadata": {
            "description": "The location where the resources will be created."
        }
    }
},
"variables": {},
"resources": [
    {
        "type": "Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts",
        "apiVersion": "2022-09-01",
        "name": "[parameters('storageAccountName')]",
        "location": "[parameters('location')]",
        "sku": {
            "name": "Standard_RAGRS",
            "tier": "Standard"
        },
        "kind": "StorageV2",
        "properties": {
            "supportsHttpsTrafficOnly": true,
            "encryption": {
                "requireInfrastructureEncryption": false,
                "services": {
                    "file": {
                        "keyType": "Account",
                        "enabled": true
                    },
                    "blob": {
                        "keyType": "Account",
                        "enabled": true
                    }
                },
                "keySource": "Microsoft.Storage"
            },
            "accessTier": "Hot",
            "networkAcls": {
                "bypass": "AzureServices",
                "virtualNetworkRules": [],
                "ipRules": [],
                "defaultAction": "Allow"
            },
            "allowBlobPublicAccess": true,
            "allowCrossTenantReplication": true,
            "allowSharedKeyAccess": true,
            "defaultToOAuthAuthentication": false,
            "dnsEndpointType": "Standard",
            "minimumTlsVersion": "TLS1_2",
            "publicNetworkAccess": "Enabled"
        }
    },
    {
        "type": "Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts/fileServices/shares",
        "apiVersion": "2019-06-01",
        "name": "[concat(parameters('storageAccountName'), '/default/', parameters('fileShareName'))]",
        "dependsOn": [
            "[resourceId('Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts', parameters('storageAccountName'))]"
        ],
        "properties": {
            "accessTier": "TransactionOptimized",
            "shareQuota": 5120,
            "enabledProtocols": "SMB"
        }
    }
],
"outputs": {
    "storageAccountResourceId": {
        "type": "object",
        "value": "[resourceId('Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts', parameters('storageAccountName'))]",
        "metadata": {
            "description": "The Resource Id of the Storage Account."
        }
    }
}
```

}

when I run this using Powershell commend i got error like this

Line |
15 |  New-AzResourceGroupDeployment `
|  ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
| 09:22:23 - The deployment 'deploy' failed with error(s). Showing 1 out of 1 error(s). Status Message: Unable to process template
| language expressions for resource
| '/subscriptions/subscribtionid/resourceGroups/MSFT-assessment/providers/Microsoft.Resources/deployments/linkedTemplate' at line '172' and column '9'. 'The language expression property 'templatelink' doesn't exist, available properties are 'template, templateHash, parameters, mode, provisioningState'.' (Code:InvalidTemplate)  CorrelationId: df65adfa-1459-4e81-83c8-7f89c3e81128

Requirments:
I need to create two following resources in azure which is 'azure storage account' and 'azure storage sync service' using ARM Templates.

Steps:
I've two ARM template one is for creating 'azure storage account' another one is for creating 'azure storage sync service'.

1. Need to create a 'azure storage account' from template number one it has to return 'azure storage account resource-id'
2. Then need to create 'azure storage sync service' using that 'azure storage account resource-id'